# Remove sound emitted after evaluation

Tags: front-end, sound

After the evaluation of a cell *Mathematica* emits a sounds: how can I remove it?

If needed, I use v.10 on a Windows 8.1 64 bits machine.

Comment: This is not standard behavior, on any platform, I think.

Comment: @Pirx So this means that something is off? This happens even if I calculate `1+1`.

Comment: Yes, none of the versions of Mma I have used have done this.

Comment: Check _preferences -> Messages_ and see if anything is off.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a non standard `EvaluationCompletionAction` setting.

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction] = {}
```

should clear it.

It can have `"Beep"` value which should behave the way you describe, otoh I'm not able to reproduce it with this option. It may be OS dependent as even documentation says: \

> This function has not been fully integrated into the long-term Wolfram Language, and is subject to change.

Alternatively, check values of `$Post` and friends or other options like `CellEpilog`.