# Mathematica emits a beep after any evaluation - how to remove it?

Tags: evaluation, sound

Without any obvious reason Mathematica started to emit a beep after each evaluation, even when it is error free. Why is that, and how can I turn it off? I tried restarting Mathematica to no avail, and [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127591/remove-sound-emitted-after-evaluation) did not help either.

Comment: Which MMA are you running, and on which operating system?

Comment: Go to Help -> Why the Beep...? and see what it says.

Comment: try resetting Mathematica as explained here https://support.wolfram.com/12464?src=mathematica

Comment: @Szabolcs This did the trick. I have activated automating save after evaluation, but the notebook I am using was still not saved and hence the beep. Thanks a lot, I would have never thought of that.

Comment: @Jxx It'd be nice if you could post a self-answer where you mention both Help -> Why The Beep and what the problem turned out to be in the end.

Comment: @Szabolcs Done!

Answer (score 6):

You can open <kbd>Option Inspector</kbd> and change the prompt of calculation completion to other options.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately "beep" was already not active there. But the problem was solved in the comments above. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I activated the automatic save after each evaluation, but was working on a notebook that had not been saved yet - hence the beep. As mentioned in the comments, going to Help and clicking on Why the Beep? showed clearly why this was happening:

[image]